# Possible hacking of my OnePlus6. Contacts disappearing under 'Speed dial'

Tags: contacts, contact-shortcut, oneplus-6

The speed dial section in my One Plus 6, until now had a list of contacts who I used to call recently and/or contacts who I used to call on a frequent basis, never used to be a speed dial contact that I had manually added.

But now, all of a sudden, it's empty.
What can be the reason? Is there a good chance my phone is hacked?

Can someone please me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that your phone has been hacked. There have been other people complaining about the same problem has shown in the [OnePlus Forum](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/auto-clearing-speed-dial.987921/) and even [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/bcdaqs/speed_dial_list_empty_op_6t/). It must be a problem with the app itself. One simple solution will be to use another Phone app. Or if there is an update to the OS <strike>or Phone app</strike>, then update it to the latest version and check if the problem persists.

Comment: thank you so much! But how can I check if there are updates to the Phone App in particular?

Comment: Usually it should come with an update of the OS. You will have to wait for OnePlus to give an answer to the problem

Comment: If (and only if the answer) the answer is satisfactory, you ca mark it as "accepted" as shown [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour).